# Trying to retrieve element after the last occurence of a special token in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

I insert  token at the end of each sentence but they are case when the re is not that token what I would like to do is to retrieve the sentence after the last special token  if there exist.

```
text = ["j’imagine une fourchette entre 40 et 65€ , prix auquel je l’achèterai sans doute.<stop> Au vu de la double fonction (2x25€) , de la technicité et de l’ingéniosité je pense que cela serait un prix très correct .<stop> A voir les matériaux utilisés pour un prix plus précis", "ma seule interrogation est « où seront commercialisées les bobines de fils"]


if "<stop>" in text:
    print(text)
    x =re.search("/[^<stop>]*$/",text)
    print(x)
    sentences = text.split("<stop>") 
else:
    print(text)
    sentences = text 
        
sentences = sentences[:-1]
sentences = [s.strip() for s in sentences]
```

I tried this but does not work. Give me None.

Comment: What would you want? `'ma seule interrogation est « où seront commercialisées les bobines de fils'`? If you simply loop over your list, your code will already give it. And unrelated but *où est le rapport entre une fourchette et une bobine de fil?* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the re.seach part and append the last part of the split to the array. But note that that you have to loop the initial list.

You can add `if s` at the end of list comprehension to remove empty entries from the list.

```
text = [
    "j’imagine une fourchette entre 40 et 65€ , prix auquel je l’achèterai sans doute.<stop> Au vu de la double fonction (2x25€) , de la technicité et de l’ingéniosité je pense que cela serait un prix très correct .<stop> A voir les matériaux utilisés pour un prix plus précis",
    "ma seule interrogation est « où seront commercialisées les bobines de fils", "<stop>"]

sentences = []
for s in text:
    sentences.append(s.split("<stop>")[-1])

sentences = [s.strip() for s in sentences if s]
print(sentences)
```

Output

```
['A voir les matériaux utilisés pour un prix plus précis',
'ma seule interrogation est « où seront commercialisées les bobines de fils']
```